Spring Boot cronjob using class program
Now the client wants me to run a cronjob without using the default spring boot cronjob feature, so I cannot use the @EnableScheduling.
Inside this project I am using Spring Boot as the backend, and it will compiled as a web-application.war file.
I have a class called CronJobHandler implemented the CommandLineRunner
package company.project.cronjobs;

public class CronJobHandler implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CronJobHandler.class, args);
    }
}

and inside my crontab it will trigger the cronjob using shell script
* * * * * /opt/tmp/cronjob.sh

inside the /opt/tmp/cronjob.sh
it should use the java command the run that specific command line class (which is CronJobHandler .
As I am going to reuse some functions on CronJobHandler , for example I have defined some functions on UserService interface class, and the concrete logic is defined inside UserServiceImpl @Service class which has been implemented the UserService interface
import company.project.servic.UserService;
import company.project.entity.User;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    System.out.println("start running cronjob handler");
    
    //getting user using service class from spring boot feature
    User user = userService.getUser(1);
}

what is the solution of this approach? Thank you!!
I have tried to compile the project like this:
mvn clean package

then my shell script looks like this:
# Construct the classpath
JAVA_CLASSPATH="../target/web-application.war:../target/web-application/WEB-INF/classes:../target/web-application/WEB-INF/lib/*"
MAIN_CLASS="comany.project.cronjobs.CronJobHandler"

# Run the compiled class
java -classpath "$JAVA_CLASSPATH" "$MAIN_CLASS"

but it seems some spring boot features did not apply to process when I am running java command
as some error messages like the below shown on my terminal:
Description:

Field userService in company.project.cronjobs.CronJobHandler required a bean of type 'company.project.services.UserService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'company.project.services.UserService' in your configuration.

when I deploy this war into my wildfly service, everything's fine, so I think the problem exists on how to run the java command. Thank You!!

The error message means that there is no UserService provided. Is there anything that is not being shown? Does this UserService exist?

Spring Boot 101 - for @Autowired to work you need to start the application as Spring Application (not using new)

@pebbleunit thanks for you reply, the UserService is existed on my program and when I deployed the whole war program into wildfly, everything's good, so I think it might related to the shell script java command I am running at, it should contain the UserSerice class? but how to ? or the spring boot feature didn't fully support when I am running java command.

@asgarov1 as the command should be running periodically, client said when starting the application server takes a lot of resources on the server, so they don't allow me to start the application server on every cronjob task. So I cannot use the spring boot feature inside this cronjob class? and for better code management, let's say if I want to use a emailService sendEmail function, should I rewrite the program without any spring boot function inside the class, then I can call this function with (for main application) or without (for cronjob) spring boot framework? Thank you for your reply :)
